# How can i make an ASPX page to be viewed for certain amount of time and then moving to other page

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am having a change password page in that when the user change his password and click on submit i will show a message and will redirect to main form. But the text which i like to display is not displaying. What i need is i would like to have the page in the same form for few amount of time and then redirect to the desired one. Any idea please

I use the following code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">function LoadPage()

    {

   var v =setTimeout("MovePage()",5000); //will call the MovePage() function after 5 seconds

}
  function MovePage()

 {

      location.href='/FedData/newRoutingNumbervalidator.aspx';

      }
</script>
```

and for button i use the following OnClientClick="javascript:LoadPage();"  this doesn't work for me

Comment: from ur question I came to know that you want to display some message after the user changes the password and after some time the page is redirected to some other page?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript setTimeout..

```
exa: setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = <YOUR_NEW_URL>}, 1000) //1000 ms
```

Comment: Can i move to aspx page by giving some.aspx  at .href

Comment: Yes, you can assign any valid URL even that of an external site.

Comment: I edited my question with adding what i did can you tell what's the mistake in that

Comment: Is your application hosted as a root site or a virtual directory? Also can you specify what is teh error you are getting? If it is not a root site then you can't have your URL starting with "/", because it refers to root site and the URI would result in a 404 error

Comment: No error is displaying but the page is not getting displayed if the same i use in body load it is working fine

Comment: Ok...thts weird... Is it possible to post the HTML of the page under question?

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ unless there is a way to post an attachment in SO.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you:

[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery)

[How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)